# Relation between extension of scalars and restriction of scalars

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

Let $A = k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$, and let $\mathfrak{m} \leq A$ be the maximal ideal generated by $x_1, \dots, x_n$. Note that $\mathfrak{m}$ is an $A$-module, so if $M$ is an $A$-module, then the quotient $M / \mathfrak{m}M$ is an $A$-module. It seems that there are two equivalent ways to give $M / \mathfrak{m}M$ the structure of a $k$-module.

First, we have an natural map $k \to A$ since $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is a $k$-algebra. This induces a natural $k$-action on $M / \mathfrak{m}M$ by *restriction of scalars*.

Second, we have a quotient map $A \to A / \mathfrak{m}$. This gives the tensor product $(A / \mathfrak{m}) \otimes_A M$ the structure of an $(A / \mathfrak{m})$-module by *extension of scalars*. Observe that $A / \mathfrak{m} \cong k$ and $(A / \mathfrak{m}) \otimes_A M \cong M / \mathfrak{m}M$, and thus we have another $k$-action on $M / \mathfrak{m}M$.

After constructing both these $k$-actions on $M / \mathfrak{m}M$, it is not difficult to verify that they are in fact the same. However, it is not obvious to me why, a priori, one should expect these two constructions to be the same. There are a few things that might indicate something deeper going on here:

- The composition of the maps $k \to A$ and $A \to A / \mathfrak{m}$ is an isomorphism.
- Restriction/extension of scalars are apparently adjoint functors, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings). (Though I'm not too familiar with what exactly that means.)

Does anyone know if there is a deeper reason for all this? Or is it just an interesting coincidence?

**Edit:** In case it helps, here is the context where I thought of this. If $M = \mathfrak{m}$, then the $k$-module we are concerned with is $\mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}^2$. The two interpretations of this $k$-action allow for quick proofs of the following separate facts:

1. If we interpret the $k$-action as restriction of scalars, then $\mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}^2$ is just a quotient of $k$-vector spaces. It is easy to see that $\mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}^2$ is a vector space of dimension $n$ (for instance, by applying the first isomorphism theorem to the projection map $\mathfrak{m} \to \mathrm{span}_k\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$, or by finding bases of $\mathfrak{m}$ and $\mathfrak{m}^2$).
2. If we interpret the $k$-action as extension of scalars, then it is easy to see that if the ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ is generated by $m$ polynomials, then the $(A / \mathfrak{m})$-module $(A / \mathfrak{m}) \otimes_A \mathfrak{m}$ is still generated by $m$ elements. The latter statement (under the isomorphism discussed above) is the same as saying $\mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}^2$ is a vector space of dimension at most $m$.

Combining these two facts, it follows that the ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ cannot be generated by fewer than $n$ polynomials. There are of course many other ways to prove the above facts. But if, for instance, we only thought of $\mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}^2$ as the $k$-module in (1), then (2) would be more annoying to prove, and vice versa. Of course, the cost of using both interpretations is proving that they are equivalent.